# Laser detector circuit with ambient light rejection

Tags: operational-amplifier, rectifier, over-voltage-protection, schmitt-trigger, band-pass

I recently asked [how to best detect dropped balls via laser detection.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/670357/242929)

Someone suggested ambient light rejection by modulating the laser and then filtering the photodetector input for that signal.

I tried designing a detector circuit but I don't have much experience and wanted to ask if this is a sensible solution or if there is something wrong with it.

[image: circuit]

It takes the photodetector input (it has its own battery, therefore represented as a voltage source, the level is as measured) and applies a bandpass filter for the laser frequency. Then a rectifier and Schmitt trigger convert it to a digital signal.

I would use a TC7660 charge pump or similar to create the negative rail.

Since the detector can output voltages up to 12V, I think I also need to put in overvoltage protection TVS diodes but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Have you considered lock-in amplifier? It’s capable of finding very small signals. But might not be that fast because it relies on averaging to find the signal.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I have not! Something like the AD630? I am not sure, since there might be a phase difference due to the detector reaction time. Would that still work?

Comment: Is it possible to extract the square wave signal, that drives the laser? In this case you can measure the sensor level via ADC at two points, say 50 µs after laser on and laser off. The difference would be your received amplitude, more or less independent of ambient light.

Comment: @Jens yes, I drive the laser with an ESP32. I will try this!

Comment: @Raphael By the way, the ESP32 ADC sometimes has corrupted readings. Best is to take 3..5 samples and throw the one with biggest deviation out.

Comment: Yes, using the ESP32 to perform the comparison is simpler than your circuit. But I’d still include an op amp buffer before the ADC input.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt yes I will put a high pass before to filter the dc and clamp the signal to 3v3.